# Publish from lambda function in KMS encrypted SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I am trying to publish from a Python 3.8 Lambda function into a KMS encrypted SNS topic.
The code of my lambda is:

```
import os
import boto3

sns = boto3.client('sns')


def handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello world'

    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn='<My topic ARN>',
        Message=message,
    )
```

If the SNS is not encrypted the code works perfectly...

... but when I encrypt the SNS topic through the following option:

[image]

I get the following error when the lambda is executed:

> {
>     "errorMessage": "An error occurred (KMSNotFound) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid keyId aws/sns (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: d81234100-9cb4-4af2-0032-c4a568a955f4)",
>     "errorType": "KMSNotFoundException",
>     "stackTrace": [
>       "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 10, in handler\n    boto3.client('sns').publish(\n",
>       "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 626, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
>     ]
>   }

What I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS support kindly pointed my out that I was missing KMS permissions in my lambda execution role.

Lambda function execution role must have the following to be able to publish in the SNS encrypted topic:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "kms:GenerateDataKey",
      "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": "<the-key-with-which-the-topic-is-encrypted>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you post that part of code in entire script?

Comment: hi @marcin2x4, I don't fully get your question, the code is the same as in the question but only the role policy has to be changed (so this JSON should not be in the python but in AWS policy definition itself)

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/